# My function does not return the expected output and I can't figure out why; can somebody point out something I'm missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

my function has to take 2 arrays and if one of the arrays is shorter than the other it needs to fill in the blanks with nulls.

so i could do this easier now that i think about it but i would really like to know what i have missed.

the specific part of my code is the nested forEach loops i cant understand that when i invoke my function like this

```
fillSquare([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5])
```

I get `[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]` instead of `[[1,2,3,null,null][1,2,3,4,5]]`

```
const fillSquare = arr => {
  const maxArrayLength = Math.max(
    ...arr.map(arr => {
      return arr.length;
    })
  );



  let arrayMatrix = new Array(arr.length).fill(
    new Array(maxArrayLength).fill(null)
  );

  arr.forEach((arry, mainIndex) => {
    arry.forEach((item, subIndex) => {
      console.log(mainIndex, "<--main", "sub-->", subIndex, "=", item);
      arrayMatrix[mainIndex][subIndex] = item;
    });
  });
  console.log(arrayMatrix);
  return arrayMatrix;
};
```

Comment: The first problem is that `fillSquare()` only takes one argument but you are trying to call it with two arrays.

Comment: Your loops are fine actually…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging, it seems:

```
let arrayMatrix = new Array(arr.length).fill(
   new Array(maxArrayLength).fill(null)
);

// arrayMatrix[1] == arrayMatrix[0] => true
```

is only creating 1 array instance. setting 1 value on one sets it on both.

heres how to fix your issue

```
let arrayMatrix = new Array(arr.length).fill(0).map( _ => new Array(maxArrayLength).fill(null));
```

this is my version - now immutable

```
function fillSquare(arr) {
    let clone = [...arr]
    let maxDepth = arr.reduce( (c, subarr) => c = Math.max(c, subarr.length), 0)
    clone.forEach((subarr, index) => {
        let len = clone[index].length;
        clone[index].length = maxDepth;
        clone[index].fill(null, len, maxDepth);
    })
    return clone;
}
```

the import notes are you can set the length and [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) the gaps. Also check out [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you need.

Comment: I think OP wants the function to return new arrays, not mutate the arguments.

Comment: threw in a clone just in case he does.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const fillSquare = function(arr){
  let minLengthArr = arr[0];
  let maxLength = arr[1].length;
  
  if(arr[1].length < arr[0].length){    
    minLengthArr= arr[1];
    maxLength = arr[0].length;
  }
  
  let itemsToPush = maxLength - minLengthArr.length;
  for(let i=0;i<itemsToPush;i++){
    minLengthArr.push(null);
 }
  return arr;  
}

var r = fillSquare([[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]);
console.log(r);
```